# Ajax request to JSON not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

I am trying to get some data from an API that provides JSON responses. I am brand new to all this. Can someone look at my code and tell me if there is a syntax reason it won't work? I want to hit the button and have an alert pop up containing the data sent back from the request. I think this is the most basic programming thing you can do, and I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/teams/8787?api_key=********&fields=name',
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data)
    }
})
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button onClick="$.ajax()">Run Code</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function doStuff() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/teams/8787?api_key=********&fields=name',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data)
        }
    });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button onClick="doStuff()">Run Code</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the browser should know about it somehow... ;)

Comment: The browsers are still from that, they are not reading minds of the developers who created the websites ;) Anyway, it should work now. +1

Comment: This shows an error on the line with this "});" I can't figure it out, I have checked and double checked and all the curly braces and parenthesis seem to be closed correctly. I also can't get it to do anything when I click on the button.

Comment: I've updated the code (missing closing script tag in the second line).

Comment: Ok, I fixed that error, but I still can't get an alert to pop up when I click the button.

Comment: It looks like your ajax call is not firing... This is a different issue, cross-domain ajax calls using jsonp. I will look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Add an event handler unobtrusively with jQuery to `button` using an `id`.

```
<head>


</head>
<body>
<button id="button">Run Code</button>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/teams/8787?api_key=********&fields=name',
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data)
    }
})
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP also forgot about loading jQuery ;)

Comment: ok, i tried this but nothing is happening when i click "run code."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several problems:

1. You are using jQuery, but you are not loading it.
2. You try to invoke the call when the page loads.
3. The `onclick` event handler tries to invoke `$.ajax()` call incorrectly (it does not have any parameters).

This is probably all.

Comment: Meder in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11908137/548696) solved the issues mentioned by me. It should work.